# Deformation of complex manifolds that admit reduction modulo $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, deformation-theory, weil-conjectures

Let $(M,B,\omega)$ be a complex analytic family of compact (projective non singular) complex manifolds, where $B \subset \mathbb{C}^{m}$ is some domain. Lets consider a subclass of such manifolds $\{M_{t}| t\in I, \exists X_{t}/\mathbb{F}_{q} \} \subset \{M_{t}|t\in I\}$ i.e. the ones that admit (good) reduction modulo $p$.
As for the complex manifolds,following Kodaira and Spencer, we deform their complex structures via varying the parameterized transition (holomorphic) maps. Say we have got two manifolds $M_{t_{0}}$ and $M_{t_{1}}$, which are submanifolds of $M$ and $\omega^{-1}(t_{0}) = M_{t_{0}}$, $\omega^{-1}(t_{1}) = M_{t_{1}}$, for some $t_{0},t_{1}\in B$, then we say that they are deformations of each other. Now consider their reduction mod $p$, $X_{0}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $X_{1}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ to which we can attach Weil zeta functions and one his conjectures relate the $i^{th}$ betti numbers of $M_{t_{0}}, M{_{t_{1}}}$ to the degree of the integral polynomials $P_{i}(t)$ which are related to the rationality of the Weil zeta function. Can we build a family $(M_{p}, B',\omega_{p})$ where we have this flat morphism of schemes $\omega_{p}:M_{p}\rightarrow B'$ such that as its fibres we have $\omega_{p}^{-1}(t_{0}') = X_{0}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $\omega_{p}^{-1}(t_{1}') = X_{1}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ for some $t_{0}', t_{1}' \in B'$ ? Does deforming the complex structure have any effect on the reduced mod $p$ varieties? The betti numbers are topological invariants so they don't depend on the complex structure. How can we compare the Weil zeta functions $Z(X_{0}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$ and $Z(X_{1}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$ ?
Does the Weil zeta function depends on deformations of varieties to which they are attached?

Comment: All elliptic curves sit in a connected (algebraic) family, but their zeta functions are vastly different depending on the arithmetic of the elliptic curve. So even in the case where you have an algebraic deformation to begin with, there is little relation between the zeta functions of specific fibres. (To me, defining your original family only complex analytically is a bit of a red herring, or at the very least an independent question to these reduction questions.)

Comment: There is an Artin stack, locally finitely presented over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ of smooth, projective schemes with a specified ample invertible sheaf.  The closure of an irreducible substack over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ is irreducible.  But the fiber over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ can be reducible or even disconnected.

Comment: can you please tell me something about the zeta function comparisons for the varieties $X_{0}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $X_{1}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$, that are deformations of each other?